# OData v2 filter by property of $expanded entity

Tags: ajax, rest, sharepoint-2010, odata

I am using `$expand` to enhance an OData SharePoint REST query, and I would like to `$filter` on one of the properties of the expanded entity.  However, I can't find any documentation on the correct syntax for this.  I've found a few spots that might suggest using Entity/property, but after trying that, I fail with:

Query:

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Posts?$expand=Category&$filter=substring(\"Featured Article\",Category/Title) eq false and year(Published) lt " +year+1+ " and month(Published) lt " +month+1+ " or day(Published) lt " +day+1+ " and ApprovalStatus eq '0'&$select=Title,Published,Category,ApprovalStatus&$orderby=Published desc"
```

Which returns:

```
syntax error '\"' at position 10.
```

How would I filter based on the Title of the Category entity, when Category is a high level, and it's Title property is a sub-level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the slash-escaped double quote and that you're using `substring` instead of `substringof`.

Does it work if you use single quotes instead?  Or did you want to literally match the double-quote character? (If that's the case, I think you can just leave the double quote unescaped inside the  single quotes)

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Posts?$expand=Category&$filter=substringof('Featured Article',Category/Title) eq false
```

or

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Posts?$expand=Category&$filter=substringof('"Featured Article"',Category/Title) eq false
```

As an example on a public service, take a look at this query:

```
http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=substringof('Bev', Category/CategoryName) eq true
```

As far as documentation for the OData query syntax, I recommend taking a look at this page: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/url-conventions

In the filter section there are a fair number of examples you can use for guidance.

Comment: Sorry... I should have mentioned I'm on SharePoint 2010... which uses OData v2.

Comment: I don't believe this stuff should be different between v2 and v3. If you look at the v2 documentation [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/#45_Filter_System_Query_Option_filter), it still says to use 'substringof' instead of 'substring'. What error do you get with the URL I posted?

Comment: so glad you asked! `"No property 'Title' exists in type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity, Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]' at position 40." `.  However, when I take out the filter targeting the Category Entity, there is indeed a first level property named `Title` in the json object returned.

Comment: Does `Category` point to a collection of entities, or a single entity. I assumed that it was a single entity, but the fact that the error you got talks about it as an IEnumerable leads me to believe it's a collection.

Comment: I believe it is. I created the `Category` field as a lookup list, and each item in the query could conceivably have multiple categories applied.  I thought that using `$expand` however would allow me to filter on that sub collection.

Comment: `$expand` is completely independent from `$filter.` If you had OData v3, you could use the `any` or `all` keywords in the $filter to say something like "Return me all posts where all of their categories have a name that starts with 'A'". But in v2, all you can say is "Return me all posts where its category name starts with 'A'". That is, you can only filter by properties of a related element if there's only one related element you could be talking about.

Comment: One thing you can do, in general (but this might not work for the query you're trying to write) is to flip the filter around. For example, you could say "Return me all categories where the name of the category starts with 'A' and expand all posts that those categories link to"

Comment: I'd considered that as well, and will likely use that method in the end.  Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: The documentation link is no more active, however the public service example helped me alot. thanks

Answer (score 17):

The filter on navigation entities is independent of the expand.

- If the navigation property **is a not collection (1:1 relation)**

  You can filter with type/property, here is an example to search for all orders that are made by customers with some id:
  http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$filter=Customer/CustomerID%20eq%20%27ANATR%27
- If the navigation property **is a collection (1:N relation)**:

  - **OData Version 2**: when the expanded entity is an entity collection, you cannot search on both the expanded and the target entity. For example **you cannot do that query** http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/ShipCity%20eq%20%27Berlin%27

    A work around might be to flip the query (to selecting the orders instead of customers - each order has 1 cutomer):
    http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$filter=ShipCity%20eq%20%27Berlin%27&$expand=Customer 
    but then you could get duplicate customers (your actual target entity).
  - **OData Version 3** You might consider to use a custom query option (http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/).
  - **OData Version 4**: you can do a filter with the any construct:
    http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=Country%20eq%20%27Germany%27%20and%20Orders/any(o:o/ShipCity%20eq%20%27Berlin%27)